# Unable to increase the width of Grid in Vaadin 8

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin8

[image]

```
public MyTabbedForm() {
        this.refresh = new Button("");
        this.refresh.addClickListener(buttonClickEvent -> {
            this.grid.setItems(getCompany());
   
        });
        this.grid = new Grid<>();
        this.grid.setWidthFull();
        this.grid.addColumn(Company::getName).setHeader("Name");
        this.grid.addColumn(company -> (company. getCompanyCode()))
                .setHeader("Company Code");
        this.grid.addColumn(company -> (company. getCompanyId()))
        .setHeader("Company Id");
        this.grid.addColumn(company -> (company. getCompanyStatus()))
        .setHeader("Company Status");
        this.grid.getColumns().forEach(col -> col.setAutoWidth(true));
        add(this.refresh,this.grid);
    }
```

But I am able to increase the width of the columns based on the content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the end of MyTabbedForm constructor try adding the following lines

```
    Component parent = this.grid.getParent();
    while (null != parent) {
        if (parent instanceof AbstractComponent) {
            parent.setWidthFull();
        }
        parent = getParent();
    }
```

This will set width 100% to all the ancestors of the grid.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting your `Grid` to be full width. In Vaadin 8 that means that `Grid` should be occupying the full size of the slot in the layout where it is. Say that you have a Grid in `VerticalLayout` whose width is "100px", and you set the `Grid` to be full width, it will be "100px" wide. I see that you have your `Grid` in some parent layout, that may be in some grand parent layout, etc. You need to follow that chain that there is right width set there too.

Check also [Layouting basics](https://vaadin.com/learn/training/layouting-basics) training video.